# django The current path, image/25x25, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.1.1 . this is my `manage.py` file:

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(
    ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        ),
    )
from django import forms
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest


def placeholder(request, width, height):
    ...
    if : ...
        return HttpResponse('OK')

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'image/(<int:width>)x(<int:height>)/', placeholder, name='placeholder'),
    path(r'', index, name='homepage'),
]
```

when I browse `127.0.0.1:8000/image/10x10`, this error occured:

```
Using the URLconf defined in __main__, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
  The current path, image/25x25, didn't match any of these
```

I think my code is right; so what is going on?

May it cause of not using suitable middleware?
`127.0.0.1:8000` worked right.

Comment: `image/(<int:width>)x(<int:height>)/` this doesn't look like a correct path to a file.

Comment: Did you try the url without the raw string prefix (`r`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the parentheses from your route definition. It should look like this:

```
path('image/<int:width>x<int:height>/', placeholder, name='placeholder'),
```

The route definition using `path()` (new in Django 2.0) doesn't use regexes anymore, so you don't need to wrap your parameters in parentheses as you used to with traditional `url()` definitions to make capturing regex groups. Also you don't need the `r` prefix as you're not using any special characters and you're not likely to use them because, again, you're not using regexes.

More information can be found in the [docs on `path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path).

Comment: sure dude, why not